# Jupyter notebook multiple window output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a code running in jupyter notebook which continuously prints output in a cell.

When I open the same notebook in a different tab of a browser(possibly a different machine/browse/tab) I want the output of cell to appear in the new tab. It seems the output will only show if I refresh the browser.

Is there any method to make it work this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Outputs do not appear in new tabs. The tab you have opened only responsible for the output of the code. If you want different cells to show your outputs then write code in different cells and run each cell sequentially to get the correct output.